# Screenshot file takes long time to save on Android device

Tags: android, file, outputstream, android-file, android-videoview

I have a function that captures a screenshot/video frame of a video via a Bitmap and saves the image file (.png) to the Pictures directory on the Android phone. However for some reason, it takes a long time for the image to be saved on the phone. For example, I'll run the app/function and the file will appear on the phone 10 minutes later. Any idea why?

```
public static Bitmap captureVideoFrame(Activity activity, VideoView vv, String viewSource, int currPosInMs)
    {   
        MediaMetadataRetriever mmRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        mmRetriever.setDataSource(viewSource, headers);

        Bitmap bmFrame = mmRetriever.getFrameAtTime(currPosInMs * 1000); // unit in microsecond

        if(bmFrame == null){
            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Bitmap is EMPTY. Curr Position: " + currPosInMs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Bitmap is GOOD. Curr Position: " + currPosInMs, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Save file
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + PICTURES_DIRECTORY + Utilities.getDayTimeString() + ".png";
            OutputStream fout = null;
            File imageFile = new File(mPath);

            try 
            {
                fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                bmFrame.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fout);
                fout.flush();
                fout.close();

                Toast.makeText(activity.getApplicationContext(), "Saved file successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch(Exception e){

            }
        }

        return bmFrame;
    }
```

Comment: after `fout.close();` try to open it and see what is happening?

Comment: How are you determining that "the file will appear on the phone 10 minutes later"? **`adb shell`**? DDMS File Explorer? Hooking a device up via USB cable? On-device file manager? Something else?

Comment: I notice the file does not save immediately. I am using a USB cable connected to the phone when running the application.

Comment: try reducing the quality of JPEG image. I guess the file size is huge and its taking time to write that. Change the parameter "100" to "75" in the compress call- bmFrame.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, fout);

Comment: BTW your description says that you are saving PNG, but your code shows that its JPEG. Change JPEG to PNG to get png image. In that case the quality parameter wont have any impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should put fout.flush(); fout.close(); in a finally block after the catch section to ensure the file is always written.

If you are looking at the USB connection via Windows Explorer, there is a delay due to caching probably(the file is actually present on disk but not displayed). I could notice this on Samsung devices. If you use a File explorer on the phone(Astro File Manager for example) you should see the modifications in real time(do a refresh on the directory you store the pictures in, or navigate up and down on the dir).

Log the following - imageFile.exists() and imageFile.length() after the finally block completes to see if the file was written or not.